# Switch DB Schema for Service Method with Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, jpa, multi-tenant, spring-transactions

I use spring data and JPA to get my entities from DB. The system is a multi-tenant application. Each tenant has its own schema. The tenants also have a parent-child behavior. In the schema there is a `config` table. When I load a specific config record from a Tenant Child1 and nothing is found, it tries to get that config from Child1's parent Parent1. I want to achieve this in a synchronous way and just switch the schema for a single service method call.

My code looks like this:

```java
@Service
public class ConfigService {

  @Autowired
  ConfigItemService configItemService;

  @Transactional
  public Config getEffectiveConfig(String key) {    
    var originTenant = TenantContextHolder.getTenant();
    var result = getTenantConfig(key, originTenant);
    TenantContextHolder.setTenant(originTenant);
    return result;
  }

  private Config getTenantConfig(String key, Tenant tenant) {
    TenantContextHolder.setTenant(tenant);
    Config c = configItemService.getConfig(key);
    if (c != null) {
      return c;
    } else if (tenant.getParent() != null) {
      return getTenantConfig(key, tenant.getParent());
    }
    return null;
  }
}

@Service
public class ConfigItemService {

  @Autowired ConfigRepository repo;

  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public Config getConfig(String key) {
    return repo.getConfig(key);
  }
}

@Component
public class TenantSchemaResolver implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {

    public static final String DEFAULT_SCHEMA = "public";

    @Override
    public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
        return TenantContextHolder.getTenant() != null
                ? TenantContextHolder.getTenant().getSchema()
                : DEFAULT_SCHEMA;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

When my Thread already has a Transaction opened, then the `TenantSchemaResolver::TenantSchemaResolver` is not invoked anymore for the `TenantSchemaResolver::getConfig` method, although it requires a new transaction. Is there a way I can enforce this?